# How can animal cruelty be considered legal based on "cultural heritage" argument?

Tags: animal-welfare, animal-rights, legislation

I have read some information about [foie gras controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras_controversy) and have encountered this piece of information:

> "Until new scientific evidence on alternative methods and their
>   welfare aspects is available", the production of foie gras is
>   **prohibited by treaty except for "where it is current practice"** among
>   35 countries bound by the Council of Europe's European Convention
>   for the Protection of Animals kept for Farming Purposes.

And the current practice in France has been described in a following manner:

> French law states that "Foie gras belongs to the **protected cultural
>   and gastronomical heritage** of France.

My question is, why is tradition considered to be sufficient for an exemption to animal welfare laws? Also, is there a precedent in European law (this is to narrow the scope of the question a bit, but feel free to include precedents from any country) to this?

Comment: Hmm. Seems more like angry (rightly, don't get me wrong) incredulity (which I share) than a question. What kind of answer do you expect here?

Comment: More of the incredulity than anger (anger just doesn't cut it for me anymore when it comes to treatment of animals by society). What I am looking for is an answer as to **how** can there be exceptions such as the one with foie gras if the legal system is set up in a way that should not allow these and whether I can have any faith at all in such a legal system when it comes to the protection of animal rights. If there are backdoors in this system, then fighting for animal rights is rather pointless and I will adapt my behaviour accordingly (eg. fight for something else and/or by other means).

Comment: Maybe ... because the current animal welfare system serves the interest  of limitless carnism, not the other way around?

Comment: Well, while that certainly is a possibility (or, to be less politically correct, I agree with you completely), it does not answer my question - what is the legal basis for not obeying laws that exist because of a "tradition" or "heritage".

Comment: I think your last paragraph could be reworded to be more objective. It currently edges closer to an angry rant than an honest question.

Comment: First sentence stresses out it being a case of animal cruelty and one which has been proven to be one - both things are important for the question. The second asks about the existence of control mechanisms in the legal system for this. The third asks for precedents. I was not able to write it more objectively than this. Feel free to edit my question if you have any idea on how to reword it. I see your point, but I think this may have more to do with the matter itself (exceptions to law being made without any apparent reason) than with my attitude towards it.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa I've made an edit which I think is an improvement. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @nloewen I miss the "checks and balances" part a little but it certainly sounds less agitated. Thanks for editing it.

Comment: Deciding what laws to pass is a political decision, a political question, isn't it.

Comment: @ChrisW I am not sure whether I understand the point of your comment - you are arguing that the question is itself political and does not belong? Correct me if I am wrong. As for my reaction to that, while the question may well not belong (I would not be surprised if it did not), I do not believe this has to do with it being political in nature. I think it is more sociological in nature. You say deciding what laws to pass is political - these laws are, however, already passed. The whole question is "why can they not be followed?" and "why isn't their breaking punished at all?".

Comment: My guess is that they *are* following (not breaking) the law: i.e. when the law was written, for *political* reasons (e.g. lobbying by farmers and consumers, and/or e.g. the public's sympathies with tradition ... IOW political reasons) the politicians wrote the law such that it exempted the "protected cultural and gastronomical heritage of France". I wrote [an answer about laws in the States](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/863/535) -- politics aren't the same in the States as in France, but I presume that too resulted from political pressures (votes, lobbying, campaign funding etc.).

Comment: You can ask this question on StackExchange's Law website you might get an answer there faster. Additionally, you can ask a lawyer specialising in this area (this might be expensive) or ask/email your question to any animal welfare groups. In any case don't forget to post your findings in here.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking whether foie gras production is legal under international law? You give the answer yourself: Yes. Are you asking, from a political point of view, why it is not illegal? The answer is that there is -- for various reasons -- no sufficient political support at the moment to ban foie gras production internationally. Or are you asking, from an ethical perspective and presumably contrary to your belief, whether there may be good reasons not to ban foie gras production? This will invite perhaps interesting,likely opinionated and surely no definite answers.

Comment: @henning I am really running out of the ways of explaining my question so I will try an analogy. Colour red is prohibited by law because it has been universally acknowledged as bad. I mean, BAD. Wearing it, seeing it, everything to do with colour red is foribidden. Now there is certain group of people which claims that they have their tradition and it means frequently wearing red and painting with it. What I am asking is, how can that be a relevant reason to make exception to the law? Going this direction would eventually mean making exceptions to law everywhere, with everything, for everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question has a strong normative undertone. I believe the community agrees that foie gras production is cruel and should be outlawed, so I will not comment on the normative aspect of the question, i.e. whether local customs *should* count as reasonable exemptions from bans on animal cruelty. Instead I focus on the question why there *is* in fact such an exception.

First, it is not true (unfortunate as that may be) that the production of foie gras is universally acknowledged as bad. Otherwise France alone would not be able to export (not just produce) [4,560 tonnes in the single year of 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras#Production_and_sales).

Second, your first quote is a recommendation that was adopted by a standing committee of a convention under the Council of Europe. The Council of Europe is an intergovernmental organization. Article 20 of its Statute requires a unanimous vote for any of its recommendations to be adopted. In everyday practice, the Council operates by 'rough consensus' and does not always require unanimity. This is informal practice, however. Presumably, decision-making reverts to unanimity if a delegation has strong reservations. The dissenting delegation then has a veto over any decision.

I would be surprised if France did not threaten to exercise its veto over a wholesale ban of foie gras production. In fact, the use of a grandfather clause suggest exactly such a political compromise, as it allowed France a simple "opt-out" that didn't prevent the remaining countries from going ahead.

Answer (score 0):

**Economics.**

Basically, a nation-wide ban of anything is highly disruptive for local traditional business and it might be in the interest of governments to preserve traditional trade for economical and tourism reasons. One might compare it to baning of slave trade. I think we're at the cultural tipping for animal abuse that we were when the first countries started abolish slavery and that [took a very long time to happen everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abolition_of_slavery_timeline).

Precedents in Europe are, for instance bull fights. Even though animal abuse is a criminal offense, these shows are still practiced and protected (although being strongly disputed) as a traditional practice.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support that economics played a roll in the specific case of foie grais in the EU?

Comment: @nloewen Just to clarify: The Council of Europe is not an EU body, unlike the European Council.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad this question was not closed. I will try to provide some justification (playing devil's advocate) for animal cruelty, outside of legal argumentation:

- **hedonist intrinsic value** - eating foie gras can provide great pleasure
- **economical value** - any country has some traditional things that it may use for promoting tourism. Foie gras is a one of these things.
- **political/economical** - forbidding something is a tough decision within a liberal democracy because it costs the votes of those affected. Also, it also incurs the cost of enforcing it (someone has to check that people actually obey the new law)
- **traditional instrinsic value** - according to [this article](http://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/arzjl31&div=17&id=&page=), cultural/traditional heritage can be seen as having intrinsic value. Also, having intrinsic value implies high priority, so it is very hard to disregard "traditional values"

**So, there are many factors that influence the decision of keeping/not keeping some practices that involve animal cruelty.**

Fortunately, European Union tends to be against the practice of overfeeding the geese. [EU Scientific Committee on Animal Health and Welfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras_controversy#EU_Scientific_Committee_on_Animal_Health_and_Welfare) concludes that "force feeding, as currently practised, **is detrimental to the welfare of the birds.**".

Also, several countries/regions already banned foie gras as indicated in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras_controversy#Statutory_and_voluntary_bans): India, Australia, Argentina, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, Germany, Italy, Luxembourg, Norway, Poland, Turkey and the UK.

Another interesting aspect is that foie gras can be obtained without overfeeding the birds ([Eduardo Sousa)](http://Eduardo%20Sousa%20Holm%20is%20a%20Spanish%20farmer%20who%20makes%20goose%20foie%20gras%20without%20gavage%20(force-feeding%20the%20geese),%20at%20his%20farm%20in%20Extremadura.).

Another relevant example is [bullfighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullfighting#Popularity.2C_controversy.2C_and_criticism):

> In Spain, opposition to bullfighting is referred to as the antitaurino
>   movement. Supporters of a ban on bullfighting remain a minority in
>   Spain. About 30% of Spaniards actively follow bullfighting in Spain.
>   Despite its slow decrease in popularity among younger generations, it
>   remains a widespread cultural activity with millions of followers
>   throughout the country.

This article dives into the details when it comes to bullfighting pros and cons. The table within the conclusion provides some insight into many aspects of the bullfighting:

> - **Economy** - The industry of bullfighting is worth $3.3 million and employs more than 10,000 people, BUT bullfighting is heavily
>     subsidized by the government
> - **Attendance** - Only 10% of Spaniards support bullfighting.
> - **Tourism** - With bullfighting being banned in certain cities, it has affected the economy, BUT many people attend bullfights because
>     they think if they do not, they are missing out on a piece of the
>     experience. These people never come back and are often horrified by
>     what happens during the fights.
> - **Artistic Merit** - Bullfighting is not a sport, but an art, BUT killing of an animal cannot possibly be considered an art.
> - **Cultural** - In 2010 bullfighting became a protected art form in Madrid. Bullfighting has been around for a very long time and is
>     almost synonymous with the Spanish culture, BUT while it is important
>     to preserve culture, there are certain traditions that need to be left
>     behind in this modern era.
> - **Environmental impact** - The dehesas, which is where the bulls are raised for fighting, are protected areas of land that are home to
>     other endangered animals that live in the area. Getting rid of
>     bullfighting means these lands would end up being developed and these
>     animals would lose their homes.

However, for those concerned with animal rights there is good news, as politics seems to favor their view:

- [France Will No Longer Support 'Tradition' Of Bullfighting](https://www.thedodo.com/france-will-no-longer-support-tradition-of-bullfighting-1242419924.html):

> The Paris Court of Appeals handed a victory to animal rights
>   organizations in June by removing bullfighting from France's esteemed
>   cultural heritage list.

- [Spain considers new 'bullfighting lite' rules](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3493792/Spain-considers-new-bullfighting-lite-rules-matadors-not-allowed-kill-animals.html):

> The Spanish city of Valencia is considering adopting a style of
>   bullfighting in which the bull is not killed by the matador in the
>   ring.

Another example which also affects my native land (Romania) is [Christmas pig killing](http://www.economist.com/blogs/certainideasofeurope/2008/01/christmas_pig_killing_traditio).

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question. The problem I have with the reasons you mentioned is that were these sufficient reasons for making exceptions to law, they could be used for almost anything from marihuana, through drinking and smoking in public places to legal sexual trade/rape. If there really is such a backdoor in our legal system then, hell, it takes a couple of well-thought-out blows and the whole thing falls apart. <- This concerns the four reasons enlisted at the top, not the bullfighting ones.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, social acceptance plays an important role in these decisions. Unfortunately, animal cruelty is not yet seen as important (at least in most of the countries) as smoking (for example), because it does not seem to directly affect human beings which are regarded as "superior". As indicated at the end of my answer. there is clear shift towards the ban, but there is social inertia that cannot be easily ignored.

Comment: Do you have any sources to support that the factors you mentioned played a roll in the specific case of foie grais in the EU?

Answer (score -1):

Such backdoors are not that uncommon, and not just about animal cruelty, in Canada for example, there were a few controversies where police officers were allowed to wear turbans instead of the regulation cap for cultural/traditional reasons or some people being allowed to have a ceremonial dagger at schools (a very tiny, non-sharp dagger) and so on.

Basically if the government doesn't care about the original law that much, they don't mind allowing people to circumvent it for cultural reasons, since those people feel a lot stronger about it then the government does. Most people eat meat and wear clothes made from animals so they at least tacitly accept animal cruelty in their lives, so it's not surprising that they are not willing to fight a determined lobby on something like foie gras...